# Python mock - allow specific values from a list?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Say you have a specific dict you want to assert against, but you want to have a couple of **specific** values you allow in a given property of that dict, how can you do that?

```
# This is in a separate shared constants file, used by a whole lot of tests
expected_geoip = {
    "country": "Finland",
    # "city" should allow for either "Helsinki" or "Espoo", but nothing else
    "city": ""
}

# class, etc... not relevant

def test_something(self):
    result = something.query("something")
    geoip = result[0]["data"]["geoip"]
    # geoip["city"] can be either "Helsinki" or "Espoo", at random(!) (true story...)
    self.assertEquals(expected_geoip, geoip)
```

Obviously I could simply explicitly check something like:
`self.assertTrue(geoip["city"] in ["Helsinki", "Espoo"]`

But the problem is, I would have to update a huge amount of old tests. It would be much easier with something like:

```
expected_geoip = {
    "country": "Finland",
    "city": mock.list("Helsinki", "Espoo")
}
```

But as far as I can tell from the mock docs at http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/helpers.html#any, there is only a `mock.ANY`, which is too broad.

It would be optimal if I could add some modification directly to the shared `expected_geoip` dict, since all tests refer to it in the same manner.

The backstory for this is that our office keeps changing the physical location between two neighbouring cities - at least according to the Maxmind GeoIP response :)

Comment: Why not create a class and use a setter? You could set the dict to a private attribute of the class and return it via a getter.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `expected_geoip` an instance of a custom class with a suitable [`__eq__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__). The `__eq__` method is called whenever an object is compared to another object with `==`.

```
class ExpectedGeoIP:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, dict):
            return False

        if other["country"] != "Finland":
            return False

        return other['city'] in {"Helsinki", "Espoo"}

expected_geoip = ExpectedGeoIP()
```

Now `assertEquals(expected_geoip, geoip)` will work the way you want and you don't have to make any changes to existing unit tests.